# How to move an object between two points in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am attempting to translate a chess piece up, across and then back down using the `lerp` functionality of unity. However, whenever I trigger this script, the entire session freezes.

Using the unity debugger, I have narrowed the problem down to this section of code.

```
            do
        {
            float distCovered = (Time.time - startTime) * speed;
            fracJourney = distCovered / journeyLength;
            Debug.Log(fracJourney);
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPoint, endPoint, speed);
        } while (fracJourney <= 1);
```

because it would appear that none of the variables are altering and consequently, the entire loop is infinite.

Here is the entire section of code dedicated to handling the movement (the vector values are currently arbitrary).

```
    public class MovePiece : MonoBehaviour {
    Vector3 startPoint;
    Vector3 endPoint;
    float speed = 10;
    float startTime;
    private bool moving = false;
    private bool up = false;
    private bool across = false;
    private bool down = false;
    public void Start()
    {
        startPoint = gameObject.GetComponent<Transform>().position;
        startTime = Time.time;
        moving = true;
        Debug.Log("Moving Piece");
    }

    void Update() {
        if (!moving)
        {
            Destroy(this);
            return;
        }
        moveManager();
            }
    void moveManager()
    {
        if (!up)
        {
            lerpUp();
            return;
        }
        if (!across)
        {
            lerpAcross();
            return;
        }
        if (!down)
        {
            lerpDown();
            return;
        }
    }

    private void lerpUp()
    {
        Debug.Log("Upwards");
        startPoint = gameObject.GetComponent<Transform>().position;
        endPoint = startPoint + new Vector3(0, 0, 50);
        float journeyLength = Vector3.Distance(startPoint, endPoint);
        float fracJourney;
        do
        {
            float distCovered = (Time.time - startTime) * speed;
            fracJourney = distCovered / journeyLength;
            Debug.Log(fracJourney);
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPoint, endPoint, speed);
        } while (fracJourney <= 1);
        up = true;
        Debug.Log("Upwards Finished");
        return;
    }
    private void lerpAcross()
         {
             Debug.Log("Across");
             startPoint = gameObject.GetComponent<Transform>().position;
             endPoint = startPoint + new Vector3(0, 50, 0);
              float journeyLength = Vector3.Distance(startPoint, endPoint);
             float fracJourney;
             do
             {
                 float distCovered = (Time.time - startTime) * speed;
                 fracJourney = distCovered / journeyLength;
                 transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPoint, endPoint, speed);
             } while (fracJourney <= 1);
        across = true;
        Debug.Log("Across Finished");
        return;
         }
    private void lerpDown()
    {
        Debug.Log("Down");
        startPoint = gameObject.GetComponent<Transform>().position;
        endPoint = startPoint + new Vector3(0, 0, -50);
        float journeyLength = Vector3.Distance(startPoint, endPoint);
        float fracJourney;
        do
        {
            float distCovered = (Time.time - startTime) * speed;
            fracJourney = distCovered / journeyLength;
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPoint, endPoint, speed);
        } while (fracJourney <= 1);
        down = true;
        Debug.Log("Down Finished");
        moving = false;
        Debug.Log("Moving Finished");
        return;
    }

}
}
```

I have been trying for days to narrow this problem down, to no avail, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
do
    {
        float distCovered = (Time.time - startTime) * speed;
        fracJourney = distCovered / journeyLength;
        Debug.Log(fracJourney);
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPoint, endPoint, speed);
    } while (fracJourney <= 1);
```

`Update()` only runs once per frame, and `Time` only gets updated when it does, so `Time` will never change in the matter of one `Update()`, so `(Time.time - startTime) * speed` will always stay the same, so `distCovered` will never change, so `fracJourney` will never change, so `fracJourney <= 1` will never change, so you are stuck in the loop forever.

If you are looking for a fix, you shouldnt need a `while` loop inside of an `Update()` function, almost ever. Use the `Update()` function itself as your loop, or use an `IEnumerator` where you can yield out and let a frame pass, as such:

```
public IEnumerator MyLoop()
{
    while (fracJourney <= 1)
    {
        float distCovered = (Time.time - startTime) * speed;
        fracJourney = distCovered / journeyLength;
        Debug.Log(fracJourney);
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPoint, endPoint, speed);

        yield return null;     //< --- yield out and let a frame pass
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm rather new to c# so I'll have a look at `IEnumerator` and `yield` however, the do loop itself is not within the `Update()` routine. It's in a subroutine called by `Update()` unless that essentially counts as the same thing in this context.

Comment: it does count as the same thing

Comment: Ahh okay, got it working now. Yeah, I now understand why my code was just simply appalling

Answer (score 1):

You've got more than one problem here.

The first is that you're using a loop inside your lerp functions.  The game won't update the render output until the *loop finishes.*  It doesn't matter if the loop is infinite or not, it's not going to execute only *one* iteration, it's going to do *all* of them (it also doesn't help that `Time.time` doesn't change during this process).

Second is that you're calculating the distance moved as an amount of distance from *the start of the application* not the *start of the current move.*

Third, you're calling Vector3.lerp() passing it a third parameter (the "float-percentage") with the value of `speed` not the fractional amount that should be calculated.  e.g. `Vector3.Lerp(startPoint, endPoint, 0.5f);` will return the midpoint between `startPoint` and `endPoint`.

Fourth, there's no reason to have *four* methods for lerping your animation.  You only need one, but you have to pass it the desired destination as well (rather than having four methods that imply different destinations).

Fifth, you're calculating `journeyLength` as the distance between the `startPoint` and the `endPoint` despite having previously calculated the `endPoint` as `startPoint + distance` (that's what `new Vector3(0,0,50)` is: a distance!)