# Moving object continuously using translate

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to move an object from A to B continuously,like 1st A to B then B to A then again A to B and so on,thanks in advance. I've tried this.

```
float speed X = 1; float speed Y = 0; float speed Z = 0;
 // Use this for initialization
 void Start () {

 }

 // Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
     transform.Translate (new Vector 3 (speed X, speed Y, speed Z) * Time . delta time ); 
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should need to use Vector3.Lerp:

> Linearly interpolates between two vectors.
>
> Interpolates between the vectors a and b by the interpolant t. The
>   parameter t is clamped to the range [0, 1]. This is most commonly used
>   to find a point some fraction of the way along a line between two
>   endpoints (e.g. to move an object gradually between those points.([read this](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html))

While for your actual answer here is code you can see:

1. http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/14279/make-an-object-move-from-point-a-to-point-b-then-b.html
2. http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/905966/moving-an-object-constantly-between-two-points-wit.html
3. [How to move an object between two points in Unity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34052907/how-to-move-an-object-between-two-points-in-unity)
4. http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/690884/how-to-move-an-object-along-x-axis-between-two-poi.html